# Division of text follow the cursor via Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I wanted have a dynamic division of content follow you with the cursor in the web browser space.

I am not a pro at JS so I spent 2 hours to finally debugged a very stupid way to accomplish this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function func(evt) {
        var evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
        var div = document.createElement('div');

        div.style.position = "absolute";

        div.style.left = evt.clientX + "px";

        div.style.top = evt.clientY + "px";
        $(div).attr("id", "current")

        div.innerHTML = "CURSOR FOLLOW TEXT";

        $(this).append($(div));

        $(this).unbind()
        $(this).bind('mousemove', function () {
            $('div').remove("#current");

        });

        $(this).bind('mousemove', func);

    }

    $("body").bind('mousemove', func)
});
```

As you can see this is pretty much Brute force and it slows down the browser quite a bit. I often experience a lag on the browser as a drag my mouse from one place to another.

Is there a way to accomplish this easier and faster and more intuitive.

I know you can use the cursor image technique but thats something I'm looking to avoid.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on answer by Alconja, this might work better:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //create the div
    var div = $("<div/>",{
        'css': {
            "position": "fixed"
        },
        'text': "CURSOR FOLLOW TEXT"
    }).appendTo("body");

    //attach the mousemove event
    $(window).bind('mousemove mouseover', function(evt) {
        div.offset({left:evt.pageX, top: evt.pageY});
    });
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Maybe there's a bug I can't see?

Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Dennis: strange, I've tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/6GAa8/ and it works for me™

Comment: lol NVM it works fine in FF3.6.

I was using the default IE splitscreen in COFFEECUP.

Cheers for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The performance issue comes from the fact that you're creating/destroying the `div` every time the `mousemove` event fires (and also binding/unbinding the event). You can simplify it greatly by creating the `div` once, attaching it to the document and then just moving it on the `mousemove` event like follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //create the div
    var div = $("<div></div>").css("position", "absolute").text("CURSOR FOLLOW TEXT").appendTo("body");

    //attach the mousemove event
    $("body").bind('mousemove', function(evt) {
        div.css({
            "left": evt.pageX + "px",
            "top": evt.pageY + "px"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: But just a one little thing,

There is still a lag :(

Comment: @Dennis - Is your div content particularly complex or are you running on an old machine? I'm not seeing any lag here... What browser are you testing in, that could also have an effect (I tested in Firefox 3.6)?

Comment: FF 3.6 and even IE

It is actually exactly the code i'm using.

To be honest, the lag is actually more than the previous one i had.

Sometimes when I drag it, it doesn't move along with it and just stays there.